SearchKit & Expenses: can't calculate with Expense Lines Amounts after Export because of Currency Symbol
I am wondering, if there is a chance to get rid of the currency sign in the results of an Expense/Expense Line Search.

After an export (Download Spreadsheet > csv/xlsx) the currency symbol prevents from being able to calculate with the amounts of the column without much reworking.
The Expense Line amounts are stored without currency symbol in the database. It is interesting that there is no currency symbol in the Expenses tab in contact view, but in the "Manage case screen" it is (Presumably it depends on the "old" Quickform view vs. the "new" SearchKit view – I am not shure). So sometimes it is somehow assembled and sometimes not. But how can I control that especially in SearchKit?

What I tried without success:

changing "Monetary Amount Display" in Admin > Localization from "%C %a" to "%a"
searching in FormBuilder if there is a chance to edit the expense blocks in contact or manage case screen
searching in SearchKit if there is an implemented option to control the amounts view

Are there other things I could try?
(using civiCRM 5.74.4 and Wordpress 6.5.5)
